# What is mean by AngularJS frees you from Registering callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and going through the AngularJS docs.
where I found AngularJS frees you from the following pains.

> Registering callbacks: Registering callbacks clutters your code, making it hard to see the forest for the trees. Removing common boilerplate code such as callbacks is a good thing. It vastly reduces the amount of JavaScript coding you have to do, and it makes it easier to see what your application does.
>
> Marshaling data to and from the UI: CRUD operations make up the majority of AJAX applications' tasks. The flow of marshaling data from the server to an internal object to an HTML form, allowing users to modify the form, validating the form, displaying validation errors, returning to an internal model, and then back to the server, creates a lot of boilerplate code. AngularJS eliminates almost all of this boilerplate, leaving code that describes the overall flow of the application rather than all of the implementation details.

I am not able to understand this two terms can anyone please explain with simple example how this is achieved by AngularJS?

Comment: It basically says that it would be a lot easier to developer because you don't  need to handle event binding (It's being done for you) and it keeps the flow of your code clean and simple (From the server to the client and vice versa)

Comment: And if you're just starting then go with [Angular](https://angular.io/) instead of AngularJS because AngularJS is old and outdated

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan for reply.

Comment: So you are talking about events like onChange() in Javascript. And how it keeps flow of code clean and simple from normal javascript or jquery. Can you please saw some code snippet from which i got clear idea.

Comment: No, since it's very broad. But you have examples in this [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/angularjs-tutorial.html). But it is true that angular makes all of this things much **much** easier than jQuery